# Применение функции Хэвисэйда

Tags: c#

Даны `U (амплитуда) = 10`,`T (период) = 1`. Нужно построить прямоугольный импульс.

Вид импульса и формула построения такая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял по формуле ,здесь применяется обыкновенная система неравенств или функция Хэвисайда.
Смысл сводился к условиям которые я реализовал в коде.

Был сделан код:

```
// Параметры B,T ввожу с клавиатуры и передаю в метод.
public double calcimpuls(double B,double T) {
    double t=0.0;
    double x,y;
    if ((0<= t) && (t<=T)) x = B;
    if ((t<0) && (t>T)) y = T;
    double z = B;
    return z;
}
```

Проблема состоит в отсутствии графика, он пуст. Строю график таким образом:

```
 // Заполняем список точек
 for (double x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += 0.01)
 {
     // добавим в список точку
     list.Add(x, calcimpuls(B,T));
 }
```

Пытался строить с помощью списка точек, но руководитель отметил, что будет лучше реализовать по формуле.

```
RadarPointList points = new RadarPointList ();
points.Clockwise = true;
points.Add (B, 1);
points.Add (T, B);
points.Add (T, 0);
LineItem myCurve = pane.AddCurve ("", points, Color.Black, SymbolType.None);
```

Здесь тоже всё было плохо, так как рисовалась замкнутая кривая не похожая на рисунок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте исправим функцию `calcimpuls`. В эту функцию будем передавать высоту и продолжительность импульса и значение аргумента.

```
public double calcimpuls(double B, double Tau, double x) 
{
  if (x >= 0 && x <= Tau)
    return B;
  else
    return 0;
}
```